# Sqoop import into Hive Sequence table

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am trying to load a Hive table using the Sqoop import commands. But when I run it says that Sqoop doesn't support SEQUENCE FILE FORMAT while loading into hive.

Is this correct , I through SQOOP has matured for all the formats present in Hive. Can anyone guide me on this. And if at all standard procedure to load Hive tables which have SEQUENCE FILE FORMAT using sqoop.

Comment: I tried loading the sqoop import results into HDFS and create an external table on the directory lcoation. But even that doesnt work, I am getting the following error.                                                                                                              Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: WritableName can't load class: QueryResult

Answer (score 1):

[image]Currently importing of sequence files directly into Hive is not supported yet. But you can import data --as-seuquencefile into HDFS and then you can create an external table on top of that. As you are saying you are getting exceptions even with this approach, please paste your sample code & logs, so that I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

PFB code

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xxxxx/Emp_Details --username xxxx--password xxxx --table EMP --as-sequencefile --hive-import --target-dir /user/cloudera/emp_2 --hive-overwrite